# Laravel - how DB class work? Especially, how DB class invokes functions from \Illuminate\Database\Connection?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to understand how Laravel DB class work.

In DB class there is only one method: getFacadeAccessor(). DB class also inherit  from Facade.

How DB class invokes methods from \Illuminate\Database\Connection?

```
statement() from \Illuminate\Database\Connection = DB::statement()
select() from \Illuminate\Database\Connection = DB::select() 
insert() from \Illuminate\Database\Connection = DB::insert()
```

etc.

Are reflection used to achieve it?

Comment: Have a look at [how Facades work](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/facades#how-facades-work). (You can see at the [end of the Facade class](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php#L213) where it uses PHP's [`__callStatic`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.callstatic) magic method to pass the call on to the real database class.)